# How do I arc iOS elements?

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

I would like UIButtons to arc around a center point.

The image below shows the end result I would like, where all of the grey elements are buttons. Optimally, I would like math that supports an arbitrary amount of buttons arced around the same center, and distribute space evenly.

Can this be done with standard elements? Do I need to create a single custom shape and use as a button? Or will I need a custom shape for each of the buttons below?

[image: End result]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CAShapeLayer`s, each having a path that's constructed out of concentric arcs, with a `fillColor`. You can achieve the gap by incrementing the angle by a delta amount for each sector.

Edit: Alternatively you can create just one path, and apply a rotation transform on copies of it around the center.

Comment: Would you mind showing a code example of how to arc an element?

Comment: You can use this method to construct arcs:`[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:startAngle endAngle:endAngle clockwise:clockwise]` and add more arcs to it

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this Github - https://github.com/Planet1107/CustomShapedButtons/. I think it demonstrates exactly what you need.

Comment: Yes, it does seem like this example is similar. But it does require that i know the point coordinates of every corner in every one my arcs?

Comment: You can always calculate it. If you want, please provide more details about the wanted the position, and I will try to assist.

Comment: Well, it has to look exactly like my mock up, and be ...say 250px wide.
Thanks for your help, mate! :)